# How to fill image at 100% height of parent and save the ratio (width:height of image)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-browser-d5qrr?file=/index.html:0-1902&fbclid=IwAR3LXPTNfumRyitqed-xzOJHEeq5PBTuLnU-V0LH-4UB8QIbPdb_hZKL1G0

How to fill image to 100% height of the parent div? Ratio width: height should stay the same.

Comment: wrap the image insdie a div. give the div the attribute `object-fit: contain;` while setting the width to auto and the height to a fixed value. the image will then fit the given height and adjust the width automatically to maintain the ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <style>
        html,body{
            height: 100%;
        }
        .custom-container{
            max-width:800px;
            max-height:400px;
            width:70%;
            height:60%;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }  
        .mid{
            border:2px solid green;
            min-height:0;
        }
        img{
            max-height:100%;
            max-width: 100%;;
        }

        #problem{
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-container d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="top">
            <h1>Nadpis</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mid flex-grow-1 d-flex">
            <div id="problem" class="w-100" >
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fhtml.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fvery-large-flamingo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="img">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Dalej</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation so we can learn how it works. That would be useful for people who come here later with a similar though not exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for your question I hope it can help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .custom-container {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 800px;
        max-height: 400px;
        width: 70%;
        height: 60%;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }

    .mid {
        border: 2px solid green;
    }

    .flex-grow-1 {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100px;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .img-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .flex-grow-1,
    .img-container,
    img {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 300px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    div>img {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
</style>
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="custom-container d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="top">
        <h1>Nadpis</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="mid flex-grow-1">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fhtml.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fvery-large-flamingo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1"
                alt="img" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Dalej</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the img to fill the height of its container which has class .img-container.

At the moment you have set the width and height of the img element to 100px. This gives a small image and one that may be distorted if the original is not square.

To make the image fill the full height but keep its original aspect ratio replace the .img-container img CSS settings with:

```
.img-container img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

This may not be what you want if some of your images are more landscape than portrait for example. Depending on the image aspect ratios compared to the container's you may get the image cut off at the sides.

If you want to ensure that you always show exactly the whole image then investigate `object-fit: contain` This may give you white space either top and bottom or at the sides if the ratios don't match.

If you want to always fill the container, but without image distorion then investigate `object-fit: cover`. This will cut off top and bottom or the sides if it has to. You will need also to look at positioning, often center will do what is needed but may not work for all your images.